# How can i use Button OnClick in Custom ListView with View Holder

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewholder

I need some help, i am using a viewholder to display from a dynamic arrayadapter.

I have list view .

Each row contains ;

- Title (Textview),
- sub title(TextView),
- Progress bar
- Download Button (Button).

I want to show progress bar and hide Download Button when Download Button is clicked. When download button in first row clicked, first progress bar is showing but 8th progress bar is showing too.

This is my code. what i am doing wrong?

```
    public class TabInComingAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView desc;
        Button DownloadButton;
        ProgressBar pB;
    }

    private ArrayList<rowObject> data;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private Application ap;
    // final private Activity currentActivity;
    Button progressButton1;
    int CurrentUser;

    public TabInComingAdaptor(Activity activity, Application application,
            ArrayList<rowObject> GelenFakslar) {
        // currentActivity = activity;
        ap = application;
        data = GelenFakslar;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) ap
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View vi, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (vi == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_incoming_row, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.RowTitle);
            viewHolder.desc = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.RowDesc);
            viewHolder.DownloadButton = (Button) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.RowDownloadButton);
            viewHolder.pB = (ProgressBar) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.RowDownloadProgress);

            viewHolder.DownloadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    LinearLayout vwParentRow = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();
                    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    ProgressBar zxcv = (ProgressBar) vwParentRow.getChildAt(0);
                    zxcv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    vwParentRow.refreshDrawableState();
                }
            });
            vi.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.title.setText(data.get(position).getBaslik());
        viewHolder.desc.setText(data.get(position).getTarih());

        return vi;
    }
}
```

Comment: put `vi.setTag(viewHolder);` in `if (vi == null)` block

Comment: it's almost below viewHolder.DownloadButton.setOnClickListener

Comment: then why it is again after `else`?? remove it

Comment: i removed and updated code but the result is same. when i clicked first button it's showing first progress bar, 8th progress bar,16th progress var etc. :(

Comment: try this code : `ProgressBar pb=  viewHolder.pB ;   viewHolder.DownloadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    
                    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    vwParentRow.refreshDrawableState();
                }
            });`

Comment: what is `refreshDrawableState` ??

Comment: it's refresing the listview row. if i don't write it it's not showing progress bar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64877/discussion-between-sweetwisher--and-de-la-vega-66).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's my solution. Thanks again @waqaslam and @ SweetWisher ツ for help.

Row Object (i have getters and setters for all of my variables):

```
public class rowObject {
    int Rowid;
    String title;
    String desc;
    String FileUrl;
    String FilePath;
    int ButtonClicked;
}
```

GetView Method:

```
public View getView(final int position, View vi, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (vi == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_incoming_row, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.RowTitle);
        viewHolder.desc = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.RowDesc);
        viewHolder.DownloadButton = (Button) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.RowDownloadButton);
        viewHolder.pB = (ProgressBar) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.RowDownloadProgress);
        vi.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.title.setText(data.get(position).getBaslik());
    viewHolder.desc.setText(data.get(position).getTarih());
    viewHolder.DownloadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            data.get(position).setButtonClicked(1);
            new DownloadTask(currentActivity, position).execute();
        }
    });

    if (data.get(position).getButtonClicked() == 1) {
        viewHolder.DownloadButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.pB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        viewHolder.DownloadButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.pB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    return vi;
}
```

And then i will use AsyncTask like [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3028660)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `OnClickListener` for `viewHolder.DownloadButton` is being recycled too. You should call `viewHolder.DownloadButton.setOnClickListener` outside of the `if/else` condition so that it sets a new listener each time a view is recycled.

Comment: Is there any change in behavior or still exactly the same result? Try to log the item position in your click listener and see if it fires on the correct item.

Comment: i add `Log.v("Position","->"+position);` in my onclicklistener and i clicked the 1st,2nd,3rd and 4th buttons. this is the result 11-13 18:18:59.664: V/Position(558): ->0
11-13 18:19:05.623: V/Position(558): ->1

11-13 18:19:06.125: V/Position(558): ->2

11-13 18:19:06.533: V/Position(558): ->3

Comment: It proves that the button listener is working fine. Verify if you need to resume the states of your views once scrolled.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have action in list item click events like,

```
   watchListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                        long arg3) { 
               .....................   
     }
   });
```

If so focus will prefer to list item click no the button click,

So better you replace the button to textview(desgined like button)

Try this, It will surely help you out...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am wrong, but try to change your `getItemId` method, it shouldn't return the position as `id`:

```
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
```

I think it will work.

Comment: Thanks your answer but it doesn't work. Same result :/