# Accessing different activities on a button press from different list-view items

Tags: android, android-listview

I am new to android and I am testing on a app where I have a list-view which is populated using a baseadapter. I want to add a button inside each list-view item which when pressed should open different activities i.e if I am inside list-view 1 and press the button it should open activity 1. Inside list-view 2 if I press the button it should open activity 2 and like that so on for n list-view items there are n activities. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1):

If you allready created an Adapter, on your xml of your `row_item.xml` or whatever you'll have to add a `Button`, then you'll have to create a `ViewHolder` and decalre there the `Button` then you only will have to make the `OnClickListener()` of the item clicked and then do your `Intent` as your likes.

Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912523/how-can-i-use-button-onclick-in-custom-listview-with-view-holder) of it and [another example](https://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/how-to-use-baseadapter-and-onitemclicklistener-in-android/).

Comment: I think talking about the button that comes insids when the list item is clicked